# How to control/pause akka streams flow in sub source/stream

Tags: apache-kafka, akka-stream, alpakka

We are using akka streams with alpakka kafka to consume messages from different topics, using topic pattern subscription. SubSources/streams are created  for each topic using groupBy().
How do we pause/resume/control the message processing for a single topic, without affecting the processing of messages for other topics.

Below options did not work.
Using RestartSource will restart the source and affects processing of all topics.
Using RestartFlow will drop the failed elements and also affects the processing of all topics.
Creating a Source per topic, is resource intensive if we have to restart sources for all topics and has additional overhead.

```
Consumer
    .committableSource(consumerSettings.withGroupId("test-group"),
            Subscriptions.topicPattern("/some/pattern"))
    .groupBy(5000, msg -> msg.record().topic())
    .mapAsync(1, msg -> business(msg).thenApply(response -> {
        if (response.status().isFailure()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Boom");
        }
        return msg.committableOffset();}))
    .mapAsync(1, offset -> offset.commitJavadsl());
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to try to control the flow of messages? In most akka stream / reactive application, the flow of data is never interrupted, you just let messages flow all the time.

Comment: @Arthur Lets say we have a topic associated to a tenant and if that tenants database is down, we want to only pause that topic till the db comes up.

Comment: What I'd do is have dedicated processes for writing from kafka to DB, reading from DB to kafka and applying your data processing pipeline. So then you can turn these on/off on demand and not worry about the data base being up or down in your data processing pipeline.